# Adding logo image to top right of page background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image "logo.png" to the background of my page in the top right positioning. I am using css to do this and nothing else... here is what i have:

```
body {
  background-image: url('logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right top;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, because no image is appearing

Comment: The image should appear. Check the path of the image, the issue should be coming for there.

Comment: I don't think the image would appear if there's no width or height defined. Trying giving the body a width and height of 100%.

Comment: check you image path it works fine for me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beav2q8t/) try changing your path to `../` `/`

Comment: in developer console you will see if the path to image is wrong ;) handy tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file path where logo.png is located. Is it in the same level as your webpage?

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z7d8kcLz/ that works. I really dont see any problem with your code

only change in your code is the link to dummy logo image

```
 body {
    background-image: url('http://www.hessionphysicaltherapy.ie/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/dummy-logo1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right top;
     background-color: #E6E6E6;
    font-family: Arial;
   font-size: medium;
 }
```

Comment: you're right.. i have the url wrong. I just need to figure out how i have it wrong haha. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate div for the logo, then experiment. Technically you should figure it out via trial and error. Load your page on google chrom, right click>inspect element and you will have a console like bar where you will have the srouce code. On your left find the div you are using and add various elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put your logo inside a DIV and put it right before the closing body tag.

```
.logo-div  {
Width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
position: fixed;
right: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
top: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
z-index: 1; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evan, with CSS you need to create building blocks. In much the way you would draw on a piece of paper you need to tell CSS where it needs to place elements. Sounds simple, but given it if 3D and your don't see the 3D it makes CSS painful. Therefore it it were me I would reap elements in different html tags  etc.

```
HTML
<body>
<div class="brand-group">
  //  use div tag for CSS background img insertions
  <div class="brand-logo"></div>
</div>
// etc

CSS
body{
 // width and height are important in the parent element. Without it CSS will just collapse 
 // going back to blank sheet of paper analogy. If you don't tell CSS the dimensions of the paper 
 // it will assume zero and start to build the document dimensions based on the elements you create
  width: 1000px; // or use 100% or 
  min-height: 2000px;

// ... other body styling
}

// I like to use a wrapper as I can then place everything brand related into the wrapper 
// e.g. logo, tagline, etc. I then position the wrapper and following that the elements within the wrapper 
div.brand-group {
  // I don't like static or fixed as you cannot use float, etc,, but I get why it is done
  // position attribute is essential as you telling CSS who you want to position the logo relative to its parent
  // in this case it is body (1000 x 2000)
  postion: relative;
  float: right;   
  // alternatively IF you use fixed or static then use this approach 
  // left: 100%
  // left-margin: -215px; // adding 15px right gutter 
  // you can do something similiar using top if you want to push to top, but lets assume this is your first html element 
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px; //you are not building the group size 
  top: margin: 15px;
}
div.brand-logo {
  // easier to position logos using LESS or SASS as you have functions
  // in pure CSS the easiest way to center the logo would be to look at the image dimensions'
  // lets say it is 100px x 50px
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px; // half the width  of the image
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: - 25px; // half height  
  background-image: url('logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: medium;
}
```